# how do i make my calculate function also sum columns as well as rows of textboxes

Tags: javascript

i am trying to create a page that has a two textboxes where the user can choose how many rows and columns they want. A grid is of textboxes is then created for their requirements, with an added column and row of disabled text boxes to calculate the sum of each row and column. The function sums all the rows but i am really struggling to sum the rows. Here is the code so far.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
        <script>
            function grid() {
            var row = document.getElementById("rows");
            var column = document.getElementById("columns");
            row.value = parseInt(row.value);
            column.value = parseInt(column.value);


                for (var x = 0; x <= parseInt(row.value); x++) {

                    for (var y = 0; y <= parseInt(column.value); y++){
                        var br = document.createElement("br");
                        var box = document.createElement("input")
                            box.setAttribute("type", "text");
                            box.setAttribute("size", "5");
                            box.setAttribute("id", "tb" + x + y);
                            box.setAttribute("name", "add" + x);
                            box.setAttribute("value", "0");
                            box.style.marginRight = "3px";
                            box.style.marginBottom = "3px";
                        var output = document.createElement("input");   
                            output.setAttribute("id", "output" + parseInt(x) + parseInt(y))
                            output.setAttribute("name", "result" + x);
                            output.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
                            output.setAttribute("size", "5");
                            output.style.marginRight = "3px";

                    if (x < parseInt(row.value)){
                            if (y < parseInt(column.value)){
                                document.getElementById("boxs").parentNode.appendChild(box);
                            }else{
                                document.getElementById("boxs").parentNode.appendChild(output);
                                document.getElementById("boxs").parentNode.appendChild(br);
                            }                   
                        }else{
                            document.getElementById("boxs").parentNode.appendChild(output);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //remove last box
                tbid = "output" + (row.value) + (column.value);
                nobox = document.getElementById(tbid);
                nobox.parentNode.removeChild(nobox);

            }
            </script>
            <script>
            function calculate(){
                var row = document.getElementById("rows");
                var column = document.getElementById("columns");
                row.value = parseInt(row.value);
                column.value = parseInt(column.value);
                var perform = document.getElementById("perform");

                for (var x = 0; x < parseInt(row.value); x++) {
                    var arr = document.getElementsByName("add" + x);
                    var rowTotal = 0;
                    var colTotal = 0;
                    for(var y = 0 ; y < parseInt(column.value); y++){
                        if(parseInt(arr[y].value))
                            rowTotal += parseInt(arr[y].value);
                    }
                    if(perform.value == "sum"){
                        document.getElementById("output" + x + y).value = rowTotal;

                    }else if(perform.value == "mean"){
                        document.getElementById("output" + x + y).value = rowTotal / parseInt(row.value);

                    }

                }

            }
        </script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="boxs">
    </div>
    <div id="matrix">
        Rows<input type="text" id="rows">
        Columns<input type="text" id="columns">
        <button id="button" onclick="grid()">Create Grid</button><br><br>
        <select id="perform">
            <option value="sum">sum</option>
            <option value="mean">Mean</option>
            <option value="mode">Mode</option>
            <option value="median">Median</option>
        </select><br>
        <button id="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I realize its probably quite messy but i am very new to this. Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just wanted to add the median and mode drop down options dont work yet, just trying to sum to columns first then i will worry about the rest.

Comment: checkout http://jsfiddle.net/2sjQp/

Answer (score 1):

Give your inputs a row and column class. Then you can use a `selector` to get the collection of inputs easily. After that it's just a matter of iterating through the collections and calculate the sum however you like.

```
<input type="text" class="row1 col1" />
<input type="text" class="row1 col2" />

<input type="text" class="row2 col1" />
<input type="text" class="row2 col2" />


var row1 = document.querySelectorAll(".row1");
var row2 = document.querySelectorAll(".row2");

var col1 = document.querySelectorAll(".col1");
var col2 = document.querySelectorAll(".col2");

var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < row1.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(row1[i].value));
}
```

Comment: aha this also makes sense. I will have a fiddle with this to see if i can make it work. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a specific class to the input elements when you create them. After that you can easily select every input in a single query.
Also: use jquery :)
The entire JS code for calculation will be something like this:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.classname').each(function(){
sum += $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: so if i give all of the input boxes a class name, how would i use that to sum each column, as all columns would have the same class name. A little confused about this.

Comment: @user2390604 `<input type="text" class="row1 col1" />` and `<input type="text" class="row1 col2" />` etc.

Comment: yeah that makes no sense to me as i havent used jquery and i need to do this in javascript. The class idea makes sense though, ive given them a class of add + y so all the boxes in the first column have a class of add0 then the next column is add1 and so on. Think that is going to make this easier now. thanks for the tip =]

Comment: Without jquery you can get a collection of elements like this `var row1 = document.querySelectorAll(".row1")`

Comment: okay i havent used that before but will give it a go. is the . before row1 just for a class?

Comment: @user2390604 yes, `.classname` is a class name selector. Here's the [jQuery Selector Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) which is easy to read and follows the same rules.

Comment: jquery is javascript, so I still think you should use it

Answer (score 0):

for calculating row total.
just changed few things in column total to get row total

```
   for (var x = 0; x < parseInt(column.value); x++) {
                var colTotal = 0;
                for(var y = 0 ; y < parseInt(row.value); y++){
                    var arr = document.getElementsByName("add" + y);

                    if(parseInt(arr[x].value))
                        colTotal += parseInt(arr[x].value);
                }
                if(perform.value == "sum"){
                    document.getElementById("output" + y + x).value = colTotal;

                }else if(perform.value == "mean"){
                    document.getElementById("output" + y + x).value = colTotal / parseInt(row.value);

                }

            }
```

Comment: ah thanks for your reply. This is close to what ive been trying to do. Just been struggling to sum the right boxes for each column.

Comment: the boxes for each column. The rows were easy because it was just output + x + y but for the columns its a bit more tricky. maybe it would be easier for me to have a second for loop to calculate the columns

Comment: The above code computes the sum/mean of the rows(each column).

Comment: yes but i need to do both rows and columns and you have changed the for loop slightly so i would need to use this along with the loop to calculate the rows to do both. is that right? or am i missing something? sorry for my stupidity =]

Comment: thats spot on. Thankyou very much.